# Can you use Gaussian Elimination for three non linear equations?

Tags: linear-algebra

The equations are

$na^{n-1}b=12$

$\frac{n\left(n-1\right)}{2}a^{n-2}b^2=60$ and

$\frac{n\left(n-1\right)\left(n-2\right)}{6}a^{n-3}b^3=160$

I know I could brute force it easily by eliminating one variable at a time, but perhaps there is a methodic way for three systems of equations containing exponential functions as well.

Comment: Is it necessary to use Gaussian Elimination?

Comment: No, but I am not good with three-way equations as I end up going in circles. Gaussian works very well for me. Your comment implies that it is indeed possible to use Gaussian Elimination for these equations...?

Comment: Gaussian elimination does not work for non-linear equations. You should think carefully about why. Think about (1) how do you go from a system of equations to the augmented matrix and (2) what does the row operations used in Gaussian elimination do to the equations and are thos operations sufficient to solve your system of equations?

Answer (score 1):

If you want something else than brute force, divide $(2)$ by $(1)$ and $(3)$ by $(2)$ to obtain
$$\frac{b (n-1)}{2 a}=5 \tag 4$$
$$\frac{b (n-2)}{3 a}=\frac{8}{3}\tag 5$$ Divide $(5)$ by $(4)$
$$\frac{2 (n-2)}{3 (n-1)}=\frac{8}{15} \implies n=6$$ Go back to $(4)$ and $(5)$ to get $a$ and $b$.